# Intellij will not detect code changes when running

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, discord-jda

Intellij will not detect my code changes when I try to run my discord bot java project using the Intellij Run function, in the compiled class files it shows my code changes yet when I run it appears to be using old code as its not doing what my current code shows. (btw I am using maven if that is of importance)

I have already tried: restaritng Intellij, invalidating cache, refresh files from disk, deleting .idea and target folder of my project, created a new project and copied the code over, cleaing package, but nothing seems to fix it.

This is the code it's running inside a if statement:

```java
if (!splitName[2].equals(String.valueOf(i))) {
    System.out.println("inproper");
}
```

This is the code it SHOULD be running (also I know some code is commented out, I already tried running it but it didn't detect it):

```java
if (!splitName[2].equals(String.valueOf(i))) {
    System.out.println("test1");
    System.out.println("test2");
    /*System.out.println("inproper");
    VoiceChannel voiceChannel = guild.getVoiceChannelById(currentAutoVoiceChannels.get(type).get(0));
    if (voiceChannel == null) {
        System.out.println("null");
    } else {
        System.out.println(voiceChannel.getIdLong());
        System.out.println(voiceChannel.getPosition());

    }
    System.out.println(channel.getId());
    channel.getParent().modifyVoiceChannelPositions().selectPosition(channel).moveTo(guild.getVoiceChannelById(currentAutoVoiceChannels.get(type).get(0)).getPosition() + (i - 1)).queue();*/
    System.out.println("test3");
    System.out.println("test4");
}
```

Comment: We don't know how you package and run the app. It looks like the code you run is not the code that was compiled by the IDE. Debug from where the .class file is loaded and inspect your build/run pipeline to find from where a different version of the class is loaded. It could be some jar file or a library with the same class which appears first in the classpath of the app.

Comment: I run the project by clicking the green Run arrow in the top right of Intellij and it does build before it runs. I'm still a semi-beginner in coding & I don't use most of the features in Intellij so I don't know what you mean by "Debug from where the .class us loaded..."  can you tell me in a way I might understand better?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on this code and start the app in Debug mode, does it stop on the breakpoint? How does the breakpoint look like? Any jars in the dependencies defining the same class as in your source?

Comment: Ok I ran it in debug mode with a breakpoint line on one of the sys outs in the current code (which doesn't appear to be the code thats running) but nothing appeared in the Debug tab thing. Also I don't think this problem has anything to do with the code because I can add/remove any of my code and it runs as if the code never changed. 
I don't know what you mean by "Any jars in the dependencies defining the same class as in your source?" but If you want to see my pom.xml for maven its here: https://pastebin.com/xF6Kgn76

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can only guess and I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Ok I made a test project with only the necessary classes, and found out that it seems to be only code inside that if statement `if (!splitName[2].equals(String.valueOf(i)))` is affected, it seems to run old code (sys's out "inproper") even though I deleted that line last night and it will not use any code that I just put in it for some weird reason, is there anyway I can keep the same if statement but fix it from not recognizing my code changes?Class: main pastebin.com/VV7CdMq5, pastebin.com/ePePL3pS, pastebin.com/CGkTkCH8, pastebin.com/bi4JF0PJ, VoiceUtils(where the problem is) bit.ly/3rOdS1x

Comment: Sorry for shortened text/links had to shorten my comment to post it.

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out Intellij was detecting my code changes, it was just that I had 3 if statements that ran the same code just for different types and I forgot to update the last 2 if statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly probable the program control itself is not going inside the if statement and hence not detecting that. Just try tagging the line `if (!splitName[2].equals(String.valueOf(i))) {` and starting the debugger. That will tell if the control reaches here or not.

Comment: It does reach within the if statement, it just doesn't recognize my new code for whatever reason when I run.